# app-debug file generated without the .apk extension in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk

I had installed Bluestacks emulator and then I uninstalled it. Now when I go and check app\build\outputs\apk\debug folder, the app-debug file is generated without the .apk extension. This file does not get installed in the phone also. Can anyone tellme how to restore back to the app-debug.apk file extension?

Comment: Your file extensions are hidden. Make them appear: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-file-extensions-in-windows

Comment: @null_override Thank you so much